# How do I deal with division by zero when simplifying equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Can I simplify following equation with vectors
$$ \frac{\vec v \cdot \vec w}{\vec w \cdot \vec w}\vec w = \vec v $$ 
to following and how?
$$ \vec v = \vec v $$

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to handle division by zero. $\vec w \cdot \vec w = 0$, right? I got as far as the following, but can't figure out how to proceed.

$$ \frac{\vec v \cdot \vec w}{0}\vec w = \vec v $$

Comment: The dot product of 2 vectors is only equal to zero if one of them is the zero vector, or if the two vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: The left hand side of your original equation doesn't reduce to the vector $v$. I think the left hand side is the vector projection of $v$ onto $w$, which will only equal $v$ if $v$ and $w$ are parallel (i.e. $v$ is a scalar multiple of $w$).

Comment: Perhaps you're remembering $w\times w = 0$ (for $w\in \mathbb R^3$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $\vec w \cdot \vec w$ is the squared length of $\vec w$.  It is only $0$ if $\vec w$ is the zero vector.

Your simplification is not correct.  The left side is in the direction of $\vec w$ while the right side is in the direction of $\vec v$.  Let $\vec v=(1,0), \vec w=(1,2)$.  Then $$\vec w \cdot \vec w=(1,2)\cdot (1,2)=1\cdot 1+2\cdot 2=5\\
\vec v \cdot \vec w=(1,0)\cdot (1,2)=1\\
\frac{\vec v \cdot \vec w}{\vec w \cdot \vec w}\vec w = \frac 15\vec w=(\frac 15,\frac 25)\\ \vec v=(1,0)$$

Answer (score 0):

Careful, $\vec{w} \cdot \vec{w}=|w|^2$, not $0$. And so $\vec{w} \cdot \vec{w}=0$ if and only if $\vec{w} = \vec{0}$.